# How does an Entity Framework .edmx.sql file generate database in a deployed application?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework, database-deployment

I'm building a c# application in Visual Studio 2010, that uses database.
To create the database I used Entity Framework model-to-databse approach.

So in VS i added a "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" file, then i designed the model, then clicked the "generate database from model" button.
After I did that VS generate a new edmx.sql file, then right clicked on this file and chose "Execure SQL", and it created the database in SQL Server with all the tables.

I had to do all of this actions manually in VS to create the database in SQL Server.
BUT how does the database get created after I deploy the app? 
I mean if i create an installer to my app, then I install it on a different computer, how can I make my app create the database in that computer?

Answer (score 1):

You must either create the database manually as you did on your development machine (by running the script) or you must put much bigger effort to your installer and add [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk.aspx) to create database from included script.